# How to draw SemiCircle using markercluster?

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

I am trying to draw semicircle with `Markercluster`. But, I can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

```
var marker = new L.circle([-22.2701 , 166.445], 150, {
    startAngle : 330,
    stopAngle : 30,
    fillColor :'#2e8dcd',
    fillOpacity :1
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ihema/d6190rb1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ihema/d6190rb1/#&togetherjs=vc9bK3UKKI

Answer (score 0):

A series of issues.

You need to include the [semicircle plugin](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle/). But you need to use a prior version as the last one is for the leaflet 1.0 beta2 version. (so you must download the js from https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle/tree/gh-pages)

Working example (*you should download the github files and not link directly to them*)

```js
var center = L.latLng(-22.2701, 166.445);

var map = L.map('map').setView(center, 17);

var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);


var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
var marker = new L.circle([-22.2701, 166.445], 150, {
  startAngle: 330,
  stopAngle: 30,
  fillColor: '#2e8dcd',
  fillOpacity: 1
});
markers.addLayer(marker);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle/gh-pages/Semicircle.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a leaflet version indeed. Problem solved

Comment: My code : https://jsfiddle.net/ihema/btdLevhz/#&togetherjs=IecbC5heTn
I created a fonction to display severals point. When I have one point(var point = [{ LAT : -22.2701, LON : 166.445, direction : 0}];)  it's OK but more than one nothing is displayed. Can you have a look?